# Is there a spell checker. I couldn't find one

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I always have trouble spelling, or more likely, getting the letters in the right order.  I can't look up a word in the dictionary if I can't spell it.  I could use a spell checker that looks at the first two letters and suggests spellings.

Comment: Many websites that accept text entry do not have a separate spell-checker because most browsers have the ability to detect spelling errors and to suggest alternatives. Which browser do you use to view SE?

Comment: Are you talking about texting spell checkers-- those that offer suggestions before the word is complete?

Comment: I call those "auto-complete" features.

Answer (score 3):

The StackExchange sites do not have a spell-checker, so it depends on your browser...

I've recently become a convert to Chrome, and one of the features I really like is its built-in spell-checker.

Answer (score 2):

> It's been awhile since I used a web browser that did not provide an integrated spell-checker. So I would say, increasingly, that spell-checking has become a client-side issue rather than something that every website should have to provide.
>
> It would simply be a waste of the development team's resources.

I wrote that [over three years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79957/98786).

Such a basic tool should be available through your browser. If it isn't, it's time to switch browsers or upgrade. There's no value to having each website spend resources providing that is already available (and much more functional) elsewhere.

Comment: Robert "Three years ago" is three years longer than Sharon H has been a member. I found the comments on Podcast 33 about the initial experience of new users very instructive.

Comment: @RobertCartaino let's please not be beastly to the newbies

Comment: I don't think suggesting someone upgrade their browser is being beastly. This is solid advice. ;) Here's a link to [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/), which is an awesome browser.

Comment: @Gene G : Robert reproduced the material he produced 3 years ago, so (I suspect) recognised that Sharon H hadn't been a member that long. He also explained why it wasn't a good idea for Stackexchange to duplicate browser functionality. I can't see anything beastly.

Comment: I guess I was reacting to the note a bit.